# Plotting OLS model created with Statsmodels functions API

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, statsmodels

How can one plot OLS models using python and a statsmodels OLS function?

Examples of these functions:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

basic_ols = sm.OLS(regions['education'],regions[['income','life_ex', 
'inf_mortality']],missing='drop').fit()

import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
formula_ols = smf.ols('MHDI_income ~ MHDI_education + MHDI_life_ex + C(locale)', data=MAs).fit()
```

I can plot a scatter plot for the functions with matplotlib or seaborn libraries:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.plot(x, y, 'o', label="data") # x and y are independent and dependent variables from a linear OLS regression

# plot x and y vars on a scatter plot
plt.scatter(cities.education, cities.income, alpha=0.66)
```

[Here is an example of the plots I would like to produce](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/robust_models_0.html), but I would like to plot the predictions of the Y variable's movement using the results of a multiple regression.

The code on that page does not work when there is more than one x value used (an array of values, like the 3 columns I called from my "cities" dataframe).

Anyone know how to do this?
Cheers!

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this? http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_fit.html